# How to make a Embedded PDF in ionic 2 application

Tags: angular, pdf, ionic2

I am trying to open a pdf in such a manner it should be embedded in the activity instead of opening in Inappbrowser or in new window.

Problem is, when I refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer link for the same it is not recognizing the `<pdf-viewer>` tag and throwing some error, Is there any other way to do the same, i have googled alot and do not found anything suitable to me. If anybody has an idea please share. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Its working fine for me on (click) event... pdf file opened in a new window